# How to extract data from Jenkins and display it a customized webpage

Tags: jenkins

I am currently using Jenkins for my build system and i have integrated several plugins with it. Can I extract the data in Jenkins and display it on a customized webpage?

For example, I am using the cobertura plugin to display my test coverage results. I want all the data that are being displayed by cobertura (eg. the graphs...) to be displayed on a customized webpage that i have (outside of Jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

Here is all Jenkins propose : 
[Jenkins Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)